# Weird Lighting in GLSL

Tags: java, glsl, lighting

I am working on 2D lighting in GLSL, but it seems to have a bug I can't fix.
My lights produce these weird "layers" that overlap when there are multiple lights on the scene.
[image: You can see the problem around the lights]

My shader code is pretty simple:

```
uniform vec2 lightLocation[6];
uniform vec3 lightColor[6];
uniform float lightRadius[6];
uniform sampler2D texture0;

void main() {

    float distance;
    float attenuation;
    vec4 color;
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        distance = length(lightLocation[i] - gl_FragCoord.xy);
        attenuation = 4.0 / (1.0 + 10.0*(distance / lightRadius[i]));
        color = vec4(attenuation, attenuation, attenuation, pow(attenuation, 3)) * vec4(lightColor[i], 1);
        finalColor = finalColor + color;
    }

    gl_FragColor = finalColor * texture(texture0, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

Does ayone know what is causing this problem?

Comment: Maybe try clamping your attenuation after a given distance ?

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce your problem, I tried [something similair in shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlySzd) but there is nothing like what you are showing here. What is in `texture0` ? And why do you use an alpha in your color ? Are you doing some blending ?

Comment: @Zouch Thanks for commeting and trying to reproduce the problem. Texture0 is my sprite sheet, which includes the tiles for my game. I bind the spritesheet and render ~200 tiles per frame. The alpha in my color was a mistake on my part, and I removed it. I edited your code to be the EXACT same as mine, and it worked flawlessly, which leads me to believe that this is not a Shader Problem. Would you like me to post any other code?
Thank you very much for your help so far!

EDIT: Disabling textures doesnt fix the problem either.

Comment: Err yes if you can add all the opengl code that does the drawing I think it might be meaningful. An [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be perfect, but just relevant opengl code would greatly help already

Comment: @Zouch THanks for your interest in this question. I am happy to say that I managed to fix the problem. I made a horrible error - I was drawing the lights TWICE instead of once. Anyway, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was NOT in the shaders (thank you Zouch for figuring that out using Shadertoy).

I accidentally drew the lights twice, instead of once.